# responsive items in terms of width in a div

Tags: css, angular, responsive

How can I make the items inside the container responsive? The container can have at most 3 items, and the number of items are not known ahead. By responsive, I mean the item width is changed with the container div when resizing and I am thinking maybe item width is a percentage value. Besides, the item width has a max-width. Is it achievable by simply css?

```
<div class="container">
    <div *ngFor="let item of items, let i=index" class="item">
        {{item}}
    </div>
</div>

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  //width: 33.3%; I was thinking something like this, but when there is only 
 // one item, the item width will become very small
 max-width: 180px;
}
```

Comment: can you add your css

Comment: I want them to be on one row when the container is large enough. When the window gets small, I want them to stack. I don't care about the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox very simple

```css
div{
 display:flex;
}

span{
  flex:1;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid green;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
  div{
    flex-direction:column
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>

<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>

<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS should be

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

And in your template you should set the style to

```html
<div class="container">
    <div *ngFor="let item of items, let i=index" class="item" style="flex-basis: {{100 / items.length}}%">
        {{item}}
    </div>
</div>
```

But this is not resizable yet. If you want to achieve that, you need javascript.